# Optimizing a neural net for running in an embedded system

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am running some code on an embedded system with an extremely limited memory, and even more limited processing power.

I am using TensorFlow for this implementation.

I have never had to work in this kind of environment before.

What are some steps I can take to ensure I am being efficient as possible in my implementations/optimization?

Some ideas -
 - Pruning code -
   https://jacobgil.github.io/deeplearning/pruning-deep-learning 
 - Ensure loops are as minimal as possible (in the big O sense)
 - ...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are your requirements for maximum inference time and maximum RAM usage?

Comment: How does your CNN model look right now? And what is the task it should perform?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using TensorFlow Lite.

It will enable you to compress and quantize your model to make it smaller and faster to run.

It also supports leveraging GPU and/or hardware accelerator if any of this is available to you.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with TensorFlow 1.13 (the latest stable version before the 2.0 prototype), there is a [pruning function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/model_pruning/Pruning) from `tf.contrib` submodule. It contains a sparcity parameter that you can tune to determine the size of the network.

I suggest you to take a look at all the `tf.contrib.model_pruning` submodule [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/model_pruning). It's plenty of functions you might need for your specific task.